# Backbone.js: View won't render when using RESTful API

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone.js. I can find a thousand and one Backbone.js tutorials, but none of them seem to cover getting data from a RESTful API. None of the other solutions I've found seem to fit my specific problem.

### Summary

The following code works when models (containing static data) are created and added to the collection, but when I use a test RESTful service, the view won't render, but I can see the response in the console.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't put my finger on what it is.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Currell/xntpejwh/

Code snippets are below if you'd prefer to view them here.

Test RESTful API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/

HTML:

```
<div id="js-spa-container"></div>
```

JS:

```
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Post,

    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch({
            success: this.fetchSuccess,
            error: this.fetchError
        });
    },

    fetchSuccess: function (collection, response) {
        console.log('Fetch response: ', response);
    },

    fetchError: function (collection, response) {
        throw new Error("Books fetch error");
    }
});

var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'li',

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.model.get('title'));

        return this;
    }

});

var PostsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    render: function() {

        var _this = this;

        this.collection.each(function(post) {

            // Put the current post in the child view
            var _postView = new PostView({ model: post });

            // Render the post and append it to the DOM element of the postsView.
            _this.$el.append(_postView.render().$el);
        });
    }

});

var posts = new Posts();

var postsView = new PostsView({ el: '#js-spa-container', collection: posts });

postsView.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working with REST API, you need a mechanism to wait for the request to succeed before doing stuff.

Here's a simple fix: https://jsfiddle.net/wnxhq98p/

```
posts.fetch({
  success: postsView.render.bind(postsView),
  error: this.fetchError
});
```

A common pattern is to fetch the collection inside the View's `initialize` and on success call it's `render`.

Or create collection, setup collection event listeners inside view's `initialize` which will render the view appropriately, and then fetch the collection inside a Backbone router, but for this to work collection fetch must not happen instantly on `initialize` in order to give other components chance to setup events listening to collection